# Creating Graph - Which Language?

Tags: graphics, programming-languages

I have an idea for creating graph like the "social graph" application from facebook,for my site.
I want this to be on application on the internet and as a software,that will the user on the center and the his friends from the site sorrounding him, with a features to zoom to specific people and to show his last message at the forum,his name,his picture and to search for a specific user.

I don`t know which programming should I use?
I know HTML(4/5),CSS,JavaScript,Server Side Languages(PHP/Ruby/Python) and C#.

I would like to get suggestions about programming language and about specific technology.
Thanks a lot,Yosy Attias

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Can i see teh codez? Don't mean to sound cavalier, but if you really know the above languages, where to start should be obvious.

Comment: Started using C# and it was pretty much complicated (using wpf canvas) and it was much complex while using js canvas api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for suggestions for technologies for *visualizing* graphs and not how to manipulate them programatically.

If that is the case, there are a couple of options that I know of. One option is to draw upon the ecosystem of open-source tools associated with [graphviz](http://graphviz.org). I've used Graphviz tools to generate SVG output for a web page. Graphviz expects the graphs to be defined in a language called DOT. Here is an example of DOT code that defines a graph of three nodes (A,B and C) where A is related to B, B is related to C and C is related back to A:

```
graph myfriendgraph {
a -- b -- c -- a
};
```

You could make this a directed (edges connecting nodes have a 'direction' which means something) graph like so:

```
digraph myfriendgraph {
a -> b -> c -> a
};
```

DOT is a very efficient language for graphs but it is not XML which might be an issue for you depending on your system's design.

If you want an XML-based graph definition language, you might want to try out the [Automated Graph Layout](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx) library which uses DGML. If you have an MSDN subscription you can download the library for free. I'm pretty sure this is the same library that is used in VS2010 for displaying DGML files. DGML looks like this for the second (directed graph) DOT example above:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<DirectedGraph xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vs/2009/dgml">
  <Nodes>
    <Node Id="A" Label="A" />
    <Node Id="B" Label="B" />
    <Node Id="C" Label="C" />
  </Nodes>
  <Links>
    <Link Source="A" Target="B" />
    <Link Source="B" Target="C" />
    <Link Source="C" Target="A" />
  </Links>
  <Properties>
    <Property Id="Label" Label="Label" DataType="String" />
  </Properties>
</DirectedGraph>
```

The microsoft library allows for rendering to a windows app or web page.